# Directx usage in UWP controls

Tags: xaml, directx, controls, uwp

UWP provide rich set of controls.
Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image control in UWP can be used to display Images .
For displaying images using directx , which control , I should use ??
Is directx based rendering inbuilt with Image Control ??

Comment: Googling "uwp directx" led me here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228375.aspx

Comment: `1` Did you profile your code? Have you established that rendering images is the bottleneck? `2` Have you verified, that using DirectX to display images has any performance advantages?

Comment: Not really . Rendering Image is not a bottleneck .But I want to understand the technology behind controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rendering through image control is not hardware accelerated .
But you can use Win2D or Angle frameworks for directx based rendering .Canvas and SwapChain panel controls along with these frameworks can be used for directx rendering